# How to add references to a WCF service application after deployment?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, assembly-references

I am currently working on a **WCF service application** in C#. There are some dependencies from both .NET and 3rd party libraries.

After deploying it on **IIS 7**, the structure looks like this:

- App_Code

  - IService.cs
  - Service.svc.cs
  - ...
- bin

  - [3rd party libs].dll
- Service.svc
- Web.config

The `Service.svc` file contains this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyWebService.Service" %>
```

And when opened in the web browser on the server itself, I get the missing reference error (CS0234). So I tried to add references manually in the **Web.config**:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System" />
            [...]
```

Now obviously I need a fully qualified name here, not just "System". But where do I get it? I feel like I've done something wrong in the process of deployment. I tried to use VS "publish" feature, but I didn't get it running yet, so I don't know if "publish" will do it for me.

**So the question remains:** How do I add my references to the WCF service? Web.config or otherwise...?

Comment: you can access the endpoint. Get the `wsdl` from there.

Comment: have you tried adding a web service by right-clicking References -> Add Service Reference... and entering http://foo.bar/mywebservice.svc ?

Comment: My WCF service absolutely works on localhost. The only difference on live using IIS is that the **.csproj** file is not deployed and therefore the service doesn't know which assemblies to reference to.

Comment: Your problem isn't what you think it is. It's impossible to say with the info you have provided but I will guess it is a framework mismatch if System is one of the missing references. Is the app pool running under framework 2 or 4?

Comment: We use .NET 4 (4.5) for everything. And I'm pretty sure the issue lies in the fact that it's not fully qualified, like for example `LibraryXYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=FFFFFFFFF`. When I create an ASP.NET Web**Site** and add references, they are added to **Web.config**. In this example, nothing was added and I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to add it myself.

Comment: What is "it"? You mean System? You don't worry about that, its in the GAC. You haven't said if you checked the AppPool.

Comment: "System" might be in the GAC, but other dependencies aren't. And I would like to manage this using the Web.config, not IIS. Also, specifying "System", like in my example doesn't work, because fully qualified names are required.

Comment: If I'm wrong you only wasted 5 seconds of your life. Unless you have changed the default configuration, your app pool is probably running under framework 2.0. This has nothing to do with how you compiled your code. Check your app pool!

Comment: I checked it: It's running under v4.0, not v2.0.